# Google Title hidden behind transparent split action bar Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am creating a program which uses google maps. I use transparent action bar with split action bar. Title Google hidden behind transparent split action bar, like on my screenshot:
[image]

How to move it upper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setPadding()` on `GoogleMap`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to keep all key map elements, like the Google name, within the visible area and away from your transparent split action bar.